# JavaMail Error. Transport.send(message) throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/ssl/EllipticCurvesExtension

Tags: jakarta-mail, tls1.2, payara, java-ee-8

I am trying to send an email using Gmail SMTP via TLS. The code below seems correct but i get an error at Transport.send(message). I have tried all the solutions i could found over the internet including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49112832/6922320) to no avail.

Here is my dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And the send email code:

```
   private static void sendEmail(String to, String title, String html) throws MessagingException {
        System.out.println("Sending email to " + to);
        senderEmail = "someEmail";
        senderPassword = "senderPassword";

        // create properties
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        // create session using properties
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(senderEmail, senderPassword);
            }
        });

        //create message using session
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

        // prepare, then send email
        message.setContent(html, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderEmail));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject(title);

        //send message
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
```

I am using:

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Netbeans 8.2
Payara Server 5.183

The stack trace:

```
   Warning:   #{homeController.registerNewVoter()}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/ssl/EllipticCurvesExtension
javax.faces.FacesException: #{homeController.registerNewVoter()}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/ssl/EllipticCurvesExtension
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.getNavigationOutcome(ActionListenerImpl.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:95)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:246)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:871)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:1035)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:79)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:731)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1628)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:755)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:516)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:213)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/ssl/EllipticCurvesExtension
    at com.sun.faces.application.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.getNavigationOutcome(ActionListenerImpl.java:106)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/ssl/EllipticCurvesExtension
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.getActiveProtocols(Handshaker.java:793)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.activate(Handshaker.java:549)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.kickstartHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1492)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1361)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:620)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:547)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2150)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:752)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.electixxx.home.HomeController.emailElectionCode(HomeController.java:199)
    at com.electixxx.home.HomeController.registerNewVoter(HomeController.java:152)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:89)
    at com.sun.faces.application.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:90)
    ... 43 more

Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/ssl/EllipticCurvesExtension
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.getActiveProtocols(Handshaker.java:793)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.activate(Handshaker.java:549)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.kickstartHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1492)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1361)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:620)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:547)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2150)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:752)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.electixxx.home.HomeController.emailElectionCode(HomeController.java:199)
    at com.electixxx.home.HomeController.registerNewVoter(HomeController.java:152)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:89)
    at com.sun.faces.application.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:90)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.getNavigationOutcome(ActionListenerImpl.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:95)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:246)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:871)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:1035)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:79)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:731)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1628)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:755)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:516)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:213)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: This is not a JavaMail problem; it looks like something is wrong with your JDK configuration.  What JDK are you using?  Perhaps Payara Server has configured the JDK incorrectly?

Comment: java -version returns
`openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)`
But my app is running on jdk 1.8