# javax.ejb.EJBException when sending emails from the application

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, glassfish-5

I am developing a JavaEE application with GlassFish 5.1, Java 1.8, JavaMail, JavaFaces 2.2, in the application I need to send emails as the method to do it is invoked, but when I run it from the server it shows me the following error:

```
Warning: javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:728)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:678)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:483)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4576)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2084)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2054)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:188)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:55)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy268.preInscripcion(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:113)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:143)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:490)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:161)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1520)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1396)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:901)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:183)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:665)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:467)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2193)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:467)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:510)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeStateManager
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.init(Handshaker.java:282)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.<init>(Handshaker.java:242)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.<init>(ClientHandshaker.java:160)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.initHandshaker(SSLSocketImpl.java:1329)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.doneConnect(SSLSocketImpl.java:690)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:569)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:110)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:528)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2126)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:728)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:342)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:222)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:243)
    at com.prueba.dao.UsuarioDAO.enviarEmail(UsuarioDAO.java:80)
    at com.prueba.model.Estudiante.agregarUsuario(Estudiante.java:19)
    at com.prueba.sessionbeans.EstudianteBean.preInscripcion(EstudianteBean.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1057)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1129)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4796)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:632)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:584)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:859)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:799)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:584)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:139)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:859)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:799)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:345)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4768)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4756)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:181)
    ... 19 more
```

I was testing the code fragment in a separate project and it works perfectly, but at the moment of executing it from the server the error happens. The code fragment is the following:

```
try{
    Properties props=new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.aunth", "true");
    Session session=Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    MimeMessage message=new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailSender));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(mailReceptor));
    message.setSubject(asunto);
    message.setText(mensaje);
    Transport transport=session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(mailSender, passwordSender);
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
    transport.close();
    return true;
}
catch(AddressException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(MessagingException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I execute the code the error marks it in the following line `transport.connect(mailSender, passwordSender);`
I have been trying with different versions of JavaMail (1.4.5 - 1.6.2), I was using JDK8u111 and updated it to JDK8u261 but nothing, I also tried to change the JAR of the `glizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar` from version 1.5 to 1.9 (As they say in the following [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49112316/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-sun-security-ssl-supportedellipticcurvesextensio)) but it still gives me the same error. I don't understand what is wrong, nor how to solve it.

Comment: Please translate the title of your question into English

Comment: I think that this may be the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49112316.  An incompatibility between Glassfish and the particular version of Java 8 that you are using.

Comment: I try changing the JDK version and nothing.

Comment: You should add the *complete and precise* details of the versions of all relevant components to the ticket; i.e. the full release numbers for your JDK, Glassfish and JavaMail.  I see you have done it for JavaMail.  (Saying that you changed it doesn't tell us what it was before or is now!) This may help someone else to research the cause of your problem for you.  Add the information to the question, not as comments.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution to the problem presented in the GlassFish 5.1 server, but when running the application from the Payara 5.2 server there was no error and everything worked perfectly, however I decided to leave the application with the JDK8u261 to avoid a possible problem of compatibility with the versions.
The download link for the Payara I used is [this](https://www.payara.fish/downloads/payara-platform-community-edition/).